# How to identify Host cloud provider from kubernetes pods?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to identify the Host cloud provider/Platform from kubernetes Pods? If so, how?

Right now, I am only looking for `google cloud`, `aws` and `azure`. 
Do they mount any specific file on a pod or do they set any specific Environment variable, from where I can identify the cloud provider/platform?

I am not looking for a generic way, different ways to find out different cloud providers is also fine at this moment.

Comment: where is this cluster hosted?

Comment: i think easiest way is to just use environment variable that you will map to the pod

Comment: I have updated the question to remove some confusions about the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no environment variables or mounts that i know of, but the linux kernel version string can give you a hint. The version info provided by `uname` or `cat /proc/version` actually is of the node not of the pod.

For example on Azure `kubectl exec my-pod-name -- uname -r` yields:

> 4.15.0-1018-azure

On GKE you should see something like

> 4.15.0-1018-gke

And AWS got

> 4.15.0-1018-aws

Using `awk` you can then filter out the cloud provider. This yields azure, gke or aws when run inside a pod:

```
uname -r|awk -F"-" '{print $3}'
```

Comment: I am actually not clear of the question. Cloud provider depends on the cloud platform we host the k8s cluster isn't it ??

Comment: Yes. And to find out which Cloud platform a pod runs on, you can use the command above.

Comment: oh you mean this is for some other user who has connected to pod via ssh and unaware of the installation.

Comment: Or some generic container that should behave different depending on platform.

Comment: @Aravind, yes. I am working on a library for kubernetes. That's where this scenario appears.

Comment: @MarkusDresch, If this works for all of the three or major cloud providers (or, platforms) then It suits my requirement perfectly. Will let you once I have update on this issue! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Markus' answer only works if you're running containers using images from your cloud provider. If like many you're using Alpine it is not going to work.
I'm looking into this problem myself and decided to use the Instance Metadata Service provided by the 3 major cloud providers. The IP address is going to be the same for all the providers, but they use different interfaces:

- For GCP, you can try to resolve `metadata.google.internal`, it will work only if your container is running on GKE (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview)
- For AWS you can HTTP GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)
- For Azure you can HTTP GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01 with header `Metadata: true` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

There's a kubectl command to retrieve the cloud provider infrastructure details:

```
kubectl describe infrastructure cluster
```

For example, to know which platform the cluster is deployed upon, I run:

`$ kubectl get infrastructure cluster -o jsonpath='{.status.platform}{"\n"}'`

```
  OpenStack
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact issue and I needed to figure out what's the best way to do it, I wanted to provide a dynamic k8s job for users to dynamically determine what's the SDK the job should use in order to communicate with the cloud provider (Azure, GCP, AWS)

I created this class that helped me to solve this:

```
class CloudProviderDeterminer:
    __base_metadata_url_logic = {
        "aws": {"url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/",
                "headers": None,
                "timeout": 10},
        "azure": {"url": "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-12-01",
                  "headers": {"Metadata": "true"}, "timeout": 10},
        "gcp": {
            "url": "http://metadata.google.internal",
            "headers": {"Metadata-Flavor": "Google"},
            "timeout": 20
        }
    }
    __BASE_CLOUD_PROVIDER_DETERMINE_EXCEPTION: str = "Couldn't determine cloud provider, exiting the process."

    def __init__(self, ):
        pass

    def determine(self, ):
        ret_val: str = None
        for cp, cp_logic in self.__base_metadata_url_logic.items():
            try:
                print("Checking cloud provider " + cp)
                r = get(url=cp_logic.get("url"),
                        headers=cp_logic.get("headers"),
                        timeout=cp_logic.get("timeout"))
                if 200 <= r.status_code < 300:
                    ret_val.name = cp
                    break
            except:  # noqa E722
                pass

        if ret_val is None:
            raise Exception(self.__BASE_CLOUD_PROVIDER_DETERMINE_EXCEPTION)

        return ret_val
```

Of course, this can be used if you are creating an instance of the class and executing the `determine` function.

**Important note for Azure users:** AKS clusters commonly use Pod Identity NMI pods which intercepts traffics to the instance metadata service, consider that when you're running such clusters.