# how to detect the cloud provider by the kubeconfig?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubeconfig

is there a way to detect the cloud provider by the kubeconfig?
or maybe use its api?

i was thinking to look on the server key on the kubeconfig YAML and pull the type from there?

azure have in domain : azmk8s

amazon have in domain: amazonaws.com
maybe by little script i can decide which cloud provider?

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: bZk3RN543VRF5QQZ5TXEY1jkFUxo1ltcOBpKNooblj2VZMLTTXlFaDYcNYWblKdMJOWMdRFM3K3ST1VULjVBQVZQUzFKozQocm3NdbRaGDsdjmQlEbRnljRmx0NeEE5uVW2BPvEZVy0BNSBZlR3RVSmCmXNdZFFDyJDmUBlMkiUShpi0UGdlQlxl5VlQMERdNVHvSZ30WRCriVMyVMSNoxZMF3E5Vi=ZWV0tuWzwTz1VtFPKZQRyrkcGQGBgdREFJRRb1Bg1TNTWB0VM9URrTFhJlTnVHNSH0aNWBVpXQUdQQUVJVVlhJkFW8Z2dyFFypGRGjWM1zRMNRTDNEFWKkRJVZdV1lW0Vs0RxWS1KcTlNN0hzMUwmpV2tY1ewlBMETdWmynzVsRKwOFdnTBltddazRVWVlVUnUE2Um0LIlTN0vVo0yRzEdQkYh6IVdVIklrop38ZOqUNSSwdSWVSmBUX9VpeD5eccdelDJVTgSiMthQTdWdzl4EDFVQ5NnVylTxcSgV2mUZRgpSZBNVNSnMrFlsRWmF04VmNz5OwZUS0dlIheOyYnlkhX1MFlm9clVVbWGV0W21UQ3Ucu1IS0QJ=1JUQMNzG3WZaZVk26c4bUWbNR5KV6mBSk4UTHW0l2Q9VZRpSTnziSCT=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
    server: https://mysite.hcp.eastus2.azmk8s.io:443
```

Comment: try `kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[*].cluster.server}'` , or something like this may help you to script out your goal!

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780093/how-to-identify-host-cloud-provider-from-kubernetes-pods)?